# Running a Game for a 2-man Party

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, roleplaying

I'm a fairly veteran DM, cut my teeth on 2nd edition DnD and have spent the bulk of my time with d20 and its derivatives. I have generally run campaigns for groups of 4-8 players and usually there are 3 core players and the others cycle in and out throughout the campaign.

In a few months I am beginning a new campaign set in my established homebrew setting. There will be only two players, both veteran role players, and we'll be playing by remote using d20 pro.

I wondered if anyone had experience running a small party like this?

The campaign is intrigue focused, one player is a telepath (the first ever, to his knowledge) the other a former member of the Magi (the emperor's magic a police, responsible for suppressing higher level magic for centuries).

I'm specifically looking for ways to handle things such as plotting and manipulating information (the players will be cooperating... mostly)

Comment: Welcome to RPG StackExchange?  Can  you clarify your question (the problem you're trying to solve), as currently we would have no way of knowing which answers would help you?  I'm going to temporarily close your question while we help you clean it up to get the best answers possible.  When you have a moment please take a look at out [About] and [Help], and again welcome!

Comment: Related: [Homebrew D&D with only 2 players (plus DM)](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/homebrew-dd-with-only-2-players-plus-dm)

Comment: Specifically; how have you handled combat with only 2 players? If you've run a primarily political game, how have you dealt with players keeping secrets from one another?