# Should I run a campaign with 2 people, or get more players?

Tags: dnd-5e, group-dynamics, group-scaling

I'm a new DM and have about two players. I am wondering if I should run the game with my existing group, or get more players.

Comment: This question has already attracted a "close" vote only two or three minutes after being asked, but, surely, there is guidance on recommended number of players either from official sources or from "good subjective" experience?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take our [tour] if you have a minute. @mattdm brings up a good point, and we certainly have people here who can help with your question, but as it is written it is not answerable on this site. Whether or not you "should" do something is entirely up to you and your group. We *can* however answer questions like "what problems may arise from having only 2 players?" and "how to do [something] with only 2 players?". If you give us more details about what problems you foresee or are trying to solve, we can better provide you the answers you seek. Thanks and happy gaming.

Comment: Presently this is also a potential duplicate of [How to make 3 person D&D (2 players, 1 DM) workable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90648/41726) which is closed. This site is best when dealing with specific concerns and problems that address your table.

Comment: More related questions: [Can D&D with only 2 players (plus DM) even work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/7355/33569) (3.5e), [Running a Game for a 2-man Party](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36845/33569) [closed] (PF), [Playing D&D 4e with two players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25596/33569) (4e)

Comment: You posted another question about needing players for lost mines. Are you asking if you can run that specific adventure module with just two players?