# How to keep an upset player in the group?

Tags: adnd-1e, problem-players

First of all: Sorry for my bad english... 

Long question short:
What can I do to keep a player in my group who is upset with my campaign?

His character was captured by the group because they thought he might be a doppelganger. He got really angry and said he does not want to play the campaign anymore.
That would not be a problem, but unfortunately I only have 3 players including him.

What can I do to keep him in the group?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exact problem you want addressed.  If it's the player wanting to quit more info on why would be good ("got so set up" doesn't explain anything).

Comment: And what do feel is wrong with having only two players?

Comment: Every group I played with had a minimum of 6 players, except my group. I just thought 2 players might not be enough.

Comment: You can run a game with two players, yes. It's obviously different, but no less workable. [I and others have written about how GMing only two players is different (and even desirable)](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/7360/321); reading those might give you some perspective on refining this question without the assumption that you "need" more players.

Comment: Are you aware of anything else you might have done that might be driving him out of the game or preventing him from getting invested? It would be unusual for someone to announce they don't want to play anymore just at one thing going wrong.

Comment: I told him to stop sticking things in his ass if you mean that (Sadly he really did that with his gold).