# Searching for a DM to help new players

Tags: new-players

Admin, if this is a post considered to be not allowed, then please forgive me and relocate.

My wife and I are interested in trying D&D. I have had interest for a long time, but since I come from a very small town in Arkansas (with very few people sharing interest in the hobby), I've never had the ability to give it a go. It is just the two of us and I am hoping to find a DM that is willing to "train/guide" us as new players. I am not necessarily interested in looking for a existing game to watch or playing with others at this time. We have been married long enough that I know the two of us are going to have a LOT of questions, if nothing else, solely based on our nature. I don't want to cause strife in an ongoing or new game with others having to wait on us while we learn.

On top of all that, I know there is a common thought of the difficulty of playing with two players and neither of us being a DM. That got me to my current conundrum.

I didn't have much hope until Google brought me here and I read a post from 6 years ago. It was about playing with only two players and a DM. The reply from SevenSidedDie is what gave me the majority of my hope. This is it [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/can-dd-with-only-2-players-plus-dm-even-work).

The reply talking about the many "story telling options" is what intrigues me. I LOVE a good story. I am still uncertain what kind of players and classes the two of us will chose but I would hope to find someone out there that would find out and say "I can work with that." And be excited at the opportunity to develop the adventure with us. I think it would be amazing to be able to play through with the understanding that the two of us would like to have a "love story" tied into the game in some facet. I am sure there are creative people that can make that happen. DON'T GET ME WRONG! We both want to be able to have an action packed, evil smiting, die rolling adventure as well. I want the game, but I want more than just dungeon raids. I think that is part of the romanticism of RPGs.

I am willing to get any app or program needed to facilitate us being able to play (i.e. Roll20, VirtualTables, etc.), as well as any suggested books/manuals or anything else that makes me as rewarding of a player as I am asking for in a DM. And I am sure it is worth mentioning what we are willing to contribute. We are in the central time zone and parents. So, for the most part, our peak hours would be from 8:30 PM central on Friday or Saturday. I can't say for sure if we would be weekly or monthly players but I can say I believe in communication and will do my best to keep everyone on the same page so that it will continue to be enjoyable.

I don't see any similar posts where someone is specifically looking for players or a DM so if this clouds the airwaves of the forum, I apologize.

Finally, if anyone has interest in helping here, please let me know. And, if you know of another place i can go to find help (no idea if there is a DMs tavern out there i can go to and find someone willing! :D ) let me know that as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the tour! This is likely a duplicate of [this question about where to find new players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232/8610). And, you're right, the site can't help you with this question beyond that linked question (except in chat when that privilege's earned), but good luck! Also, thank you for taking the risk and participating and, of course, have fun.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are looking for remote help I have several recommendations for you about finding people online:

- Check out more chat / discussion oriented places like

  - https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/
  - and this sub specifically for finding people to play with: https://www.reddit.com/r/lfg/
- Drop into a few games in a virtual convention! https://www.rpggeek.com/thread/1842932/virtuacon-17-oct-6-8-2017 You're likely to meet people there who you can keep playing with, too, I did!

And of course, check out resources for finding people locally like:

- http://nearbygamers.com/
- https://www.meetup.com/
- And your friendly local game store, if you have one

Oh, and welcome! This is a great hobby, I've been playing with my wife since we were in high school, now our son GMs for us! :)

Comment: Awesome to hear that your son GMs for you and your wife. Sounds like great family time. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will look into all of that. So cool that your whole family is involved! *Thumbs up*